# Counting the number of tasks per day when the between dates aren't included in the data

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get the count of the number of tasks per each date. This needs to include the dates in between the Finish Date and Actual Date below. eg. 14-Jan to 16-Jan needs to be accounted for in 15-Jan. So for the example below, two tasks are active on these dates so the count needs to be 2.

I have a dataframe like this:

```
task    Finish_Date     Actual_Date
abc      14-Jan-21       16-Jan-21
xyz      12-Jan-21       18-Jan-21
```

And I need to transform it to look like a dataframe like this:

```
Date        Count
12-Jan-21      1
13-Jan-21      1
14-Jan-21      2
15-Jan-21      2
16-Jan-21      2
17-Jan-21      1
18-Jan-21      1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create all date ranges per rows and then for count is used [`Index.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.value_counts.html):

```
L = [pd.Series(r.task,pd.date_range(r.Finish_Date, r.Actual_Date)) for r in df.itertuples()]
df1 = (pd.concat(L)
         .index
         .value_counts()
         .sort_index()
         .rename_axis('Date')
         .reset_index(name='Count'))

print (df1)
       Date  Count
0 2021-01-12      1
1 2021-01-13      1
2 2021-01-14      2
3 2021-01-15      2
4 2021-01-16      2
5 2021-01-17      1
6 2021-01-18      1
```